# Modoboa server not working with external emails (like Google, Yahoo)

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, postfix-mta, yahoo

I have setup modoboa server in  AWS lightsail instance from this link
[https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/email-server-ubuntu-18-04-modoboa]

Internal emails are working ( **username@domain.net** to **username2@domain.net** )but an email from an external provider like google, yahoo is not working.

Already set up with A, MX ( Google, MailServer ), TXT (spf and _dmarc) Records but still emails from external providers are not working.

**Please help**